# App crashes when voice over enabled during pull to refresh

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiaccessibility

Crash occuring when I pulltorefresh a page with voice over enabled.
The crash occuring inside the iOS. I am not familiar with this crash.
I am stuck in this crash. Can anyone please help me? Why this crash occuring? How can I solve this? Please see below the crash log.

```
Crash log:

    Thread 0 Crashed:
    0   libobjc.A.dylib                      0x30560f66 objc_msgSend + 6
    1   UIAccessibility                      0x2d5ab43f -[NSObject(AXPrivCategory) _accessibilityIterateScrollParentsUsingBlock:includeSelf:] + 232
    2   UIAccessibility                      0x2d5ad1b9 -[NSObject(AXPrivCategory) _accessibilityHandlePublicScroll:] + 174
    3   UIAccessibility                      0x2d5ad547 -[NSObject(AXPrivCategory) _accessibilityScrollUpPage] + 24
    4   UIAccessibility                      0x2d5bd8b9 -[NSObject(UIStorage) accessibilityPerformAction:withValue:] + 1554
    5   UIAccessibility                      0x2d5a2441 _performActionCallback + 62
    6   AXRuntime                            0x26af4a1d _AXXMIGPerformAction + 90
    7   AXRuntime                            0x26af0731 _XPerformAction + 254
    8   AXRuntime                            0x26afa301 mshMIGPerform + 242
    9   CoreFoundation                       0x225bda4b __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 32
    10  CoreFoundation                       0x225bd9e7 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 344
    11  CoreFoundation                       0x225bc009 __CFRunLoopRun + 1606
    12  CoreFoundation                       0x225079a1 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 474
    13  CoreFoundation                       0x225077b3 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
    14  GraphicsServices                     0x29cb91a9 GSEventRunModal + 134
    15  UIKit                                0x25c92695 UIApplicationMain + 1438
    16  Classroom                            0x000df7e3 main (main.m:13)
    17  libdyld.dylib                        0x30afcaaf start + 0

    Thread 1:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib               0x30baf24c kevent64 + 24
    1   libdispatch.dylib                    0x30acf223 _dispatch_mgr_thread$VARIANT$mp + 36

    Thread 2:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib               0x30baf49c mach_msg_trap + 20
    1   CoreFoundation                       0x225bd7f3 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 144
    2   CoreFoundation                       0x225bbdb9 __CFRunLoopRun + 1014
    3   CoreFoundation                       0x225079a1 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 474
    4   CoreFoundation                       0x225077b3 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
    5   CFNetwork                            0x220a5647 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 484
    6   Foundation                           0x2333618b __NSThread__main__ + 1116
    7   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x30c42deb _pthread_body + 136
    8   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x30c42d5f _pthread_start + 116
    9   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x30c40b08 thread_start + 6

    Thread 3:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib               0x30bc3080 __select + 20
    1   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x30c42deb _pthread_body + 136
    2   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x30c42d5f _pthread_start + 116
    3   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x30c40b08 thread_start + 6

    Thread 4:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib               0x30baf49c mach_msg_trap + 20
    1   CoreFoundation                       0x225bd7f3 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 144
    2   CoreFoundation                       0x225bbdb9 __CFRunLoopRun + 1014
    3   CoreFoundation                       0x225079a1 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 474
    4   CoreFoundation                       0x225077b3 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
    5   Classroom                            0x00106863 +[ASIHTTPRequest runRequests] (ASIHTTPRequest.m:4798)
    6   Foundation                           0x2333618b __NSThread__main__ + 1116
    7   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x30c42deb _pthread_body + 136
    8   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x30c42d5f _pthread_start + 116
    9   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x30c40b08 thread_start + 6

    Thread 5:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib               0x30bc39c0 __workq_kernreturn + 8
    1   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x30c40afc start_wqthread + 6

    Thread 6:
    0   libsystem_c.dylib                    0x30b5173c __sfvwrite + 4
    1   libsystem_c.dylib                    0x30b56e27 __vfprintf + 9284
    2   libsystem_c.dylib                    0x30b6afc1 __v2printf + 502
    3   libsystem_c.dylib                    0x30b193f5 _vsnprintf + 338
    4   libsystem_c.dylib                    0x30b19299 vsnprintf + 70
    5   libsystem_c.dylib                    0x30b71003 __snprintf_chk + 20
    6   libsystem_asl.dylib                  0x30b07e9d asl_string_append_char_no_encoding + 106
    7   libsystem_asl.dylib                  0x30b081a9 asl_string_append_internal + 730
    8   libsystem_asl.dylib                  0x30b07c09 asl_msg_to_string_raw + 186
    9   libsystem_asl.dylib                  0x30b078b3 _asl_send_message + 1216
    10  libsystem_asl.dylib                  0x30b073ed asl_send + 6
    11  CoreFoundation                       0x225e1fad __CFLogCString + 586
    12  CoreFoundation                       0x225e1d3d _CFLogvEx2 + 206
    13  Foundation                           0x23275dad NSLogv + 114
    14  Foundation                           0x23275d2f NSLog + 24
    15  Classroom                            0x0045c7fd ADBLogDebugFormat + 102
    16  Classroom                            0x0044afe9 ADBAnalyticsBuildAndSendRequest + 1230
    17  Classroom                            0x0045ef63 __ADBAnalyticsTrackState_block_invoke + 100
    18  libdispatch.dylib                    0x30abec83 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 8
    19  libdispatch.dylib                    0x30ac94d3 _dispatch_queue_drain$VARIANT$mp + 1460
    20  libdispatch.dylib                    0x30ac8da1 _dispatch_queue_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 82
    21  libdispatch.dylib                    0x30acb491 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 386
    22  libdispatch.dylib                    0x30acc8a3 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 104
    23  libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x30c40da9 _pthread_wqthread + 666
    24  libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x30c40afc start_wqthread + 6

    Thread 7:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib               0x30bc39c0 __workq_kernreturn + 8
    1   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x30c40afc start_wqthread + 6

    Thread 8:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib               0x30bc39c0 __workq_kernreturn + 8
    1   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x30c40afc start_wqthread + 6

    Thread 9:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib               0x30bc39c0 __workq_kernreturn + 8
    1   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x30c40afc start_wqthread + 6

    Thread 10:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib               0x30bc39c0 __workq_kernreturn + 8
    1   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x30c40afc start_wqthread + 6
```

Comment: do you get the same crash with voice-over turned off? Can you add some of the code here?

Comment: No, the crash is not occuring when voice - over turned off

Comment: Can you include the complete log, including the crash reason?

Comment: This is an inconsistent issue, Crashes once in 50 times, crash log is not showing anything related to my code. Here not allowing me to add full crash report as comment. Anyways i will add the OS version and some details as comment here

Comment: Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2015-06-29T07:04:42Z
OS Version:      iPhone OS 8.3 (12F69)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  SIGSEGV
Exception Codes: SEGV_ACCERR at 0xc
Crashed Thread:  0, This is the upper part of the crash log.